# How can I compile Swift 2.3 Code in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I have many issues with my project Swift 2.2 in Xcode8, the pod library generates many error, I did an update of cocoapods and library but I still have those errors, I have convert syntax to Swift 2.3 but the errors are still there. I do not want to convert swift 3 for the time being.

Here is a picture of errors :

[Socket Io Client Swift errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUAIW.png)

Thank you in advance and sorry for English errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is that [the library you are using](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/tree/master/Source) *is* Swift 3. So there is no point saying "I do not want to convert to Swift 3". You *have* converted to Swift 3 whether you like it or not. You do not need to compile this code as Swift 2.3. You need to compile it as Swift 3.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the problem because when I execute this command : xcrun swift -version => Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9, I do not know what to do, I have tried many solutions but I always lib errors

Comment: You showed a screen shot of some build errors involving Socket-IO-Client-Swift. You asked why you are getting those build errors. I am telling you why. That code is written _in Swift 3_. You need to compile _as Swift 3_. Your errors are because you are trying to compile as Swift 2.2 or Swift 2.3. Stop trying to do that. It is _Swift 3_ code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try specifying an older version of your Pod dependency in your Podfile. Try checking their release notes/docs to see if there is a version written for Swift 2.x.

Comment: My code is not Swift3 because I don't have convert to swift3 and the syntax of my project is Swift2.3

Comment: I don't care what your code is. Your code is not the problem. The code that is not compiling is Socket-IO-Client-Swift. It is Swift 3.

Comment: OK I see, Thank you, I am looking for a version for swift 2.3

Comment: Thanks, When I specify the version in the Pod File that does not work, but I have indicated the branch in PODFILE and it works

Answer (score 1):

To run Swift 2.3 in Xcode8, set `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `YES` within your projects, your targets and your pod framework targets Build Settings.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've done but always errors

Comment: Post one error. I assume you acidenntally converted to Swift3 and thus you have to fix your issues. Or: revert to Swift 2.3 Version and use the mentioned build setting

Comment: My project is convert in Swift2.3 because when I convert in Swift2.3 i have a warning :  Target has already been converted to Swift2.3 Syntax. And the settings Use Legacy Swift Language Version is a Yes

Comment: Updated answer. Apply the same setting to your pod framework target(s), clean & build.